# How do I compare to a txt file line for line?

Tags: java, arrays, text, double, line

Here's the file: http://textuploader.com/5y6xh

I have arranged the doubles from the .txt file into an array list already to avoid any String interference.

How do I compare each double **one line at a time** to a separate double down the entire array?

Comment: With a loop? Are you aware of `while` and `for` loops?

Comment: yes, but how do I efficiently go line for line...

Comment: A single while or for loop would generally be O(n) whereas nested for loops would be O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

You could brute force it

```
take the first element
loop through the array
return false if the element equals any other element
move to the second element
loop through the array
return false if the element equals any other element
move to the third element
...
After the loop is finished, return true
```

This algorithm is basically brute force searching, it's not very efficient, O(n!) if I remember correctly, but it'll do what you need. If you're willing to create a BST you can cut down the time if you're looking for doubles or ints.